# Cargar array en un select javascript

Tags: javascript

buen día
Estoy tratando de cargar un array en un select, pero no se si es posible realizarlo de la forma en que lo hago

Este es mi HTML, con estilos de Materialize

```
<div class="input-field col s3"  id="SelectVariedad">
    <select name="idVariedad" id="idVariedad">                        
            <option></option>
    </select>
    <label>Variedad</label>
</div>
```

Y este es mi js

```
const variedades =  ["100797","111920","09S352","115-135RD","11ST199"]
 console.log(variedades);
 console.log('Hola mundo');

// const p = document.querySelector('#SelectVariedad');
// p.innerHTML = variedades;
function imprimirVariedades(variedades){
    let  html  = '';

    variedades.forEach(variedad => {

        html += `
        <select name="idVariedad" id="idVariedad"> 
            <option value = "${variedad}">${variedad}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Variedad</label>
        `;
        console.log(variedad);
    });

        const select = document.querySelector('#SelectVariedad');
        select.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pero que tal si mostramos un código donde no tengamos que crear las etiquetas `options` podemos crear el elemento HTML y luego asignarle el valor de sus atributos.

```js
const variedades =  ["Gbianchi","111920","09S352","115-135RD","11ST199"]
function imprimirVariedades(variedades){
    const select = document.querySelector('#SelectVariedad');
    variedades.forEach(variedad => {        
        let opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = variedad; 
        opt.text = variedad
        select.appendChild(opt)
    });
}
imprimirVariedades(variedades)
```

```html
<select id='SelectVariedad'></select>
```

Comment: Estás incentivando una mala práctica en esta línea: `select.appendChild(opt)`, no conviene modificar elementos del DOM en bucle. Cada vez que modificas el DOM esto tiene un costo en el rendimiento (imaginemos que ese bucle tenga mil elementos, ¡estarás modificando el DOM mil veces!). Es mejor construir una cadena con los `option` dentro del bucle y modificar el DOM una sola vez, fuera del bucle.

Comment: Lo que digo está indicado en el apartado [***Keep DOM access to a minimum***](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Keep_DOM_access_to_a_minimum) del artículo *JavaScript best practices* de w3.org.

Answer (score 2):

Solo hay un error en la concatenación de las opciones para formar el inner html.

```js
const variedades =  ["100797","111920","09S352","115-135RD","11ST199"]

function imprimirVariedades(variedades){
    let  html  = '';

    variedades.forEach(variedad => {
        // El inner html serían las opciones del select
        html += `
        <option value = "${variedad}">${variedad}</option>
        `;
    });

        const select = document.querySelector('#SelectVariedad');
        select.innerHTML = html;
}
imprimirVariedades(variedades);
```

```html
<select id="SelectVariedad"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let  html  = ' <select name="idVariedad" id="idVariedad"> ';
const variedades =  ["100797","111920","09S352","115-135RD","11ST199"]
variedades.forEach(variedad => {

html += `

    <option value = "${variedad}">${variedad}</option>

`;
console.log(variedad);
});
html += '</select><label>Variedad</label>'
const select = document.querySelector('#SelectVariedad');
select.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select id='SelectVariedad'/>
```

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos, al fin me fije en el error que estaba cometiendo, agradezco mucho su ayuda.